# append table row using jQuery

Tags: jquery, append

I have five `<tr>` in my table in which four are displayed none I want when user click on Add button then one tr among of these will display block I gave name to all  like input1, input2, input3, input4 if user click first time ten input1 will display block second time input2 will display block third and fourth time the same appropriate input  will open

Now the problem is when user click on cancel **`X`** button which would be any one among of these like 1, 2, 3, 4 any  will be display none I want after that when user click again on add button then the tr which is displayed none will appear I create a var named count to controll this .. BUt fail to achieve the task please help me guys thanks in advance for you reff plz check fiddle here **http://jsfiddle.net/pnR8e/2/** for test just click on add button 4 times and then click on second or third **`X`** button and again click on add button

You can also check my code below

**SCRIPT**

```
var count = 0;
    $('.addRow').click(function () {
        count++; 
        if( $('.input'+count+'').css('display')== 'none')
        {
             $('.input'+count+'').css('display','block');
            }
        if(count== 4)   
        {
            $('.addRow').hide();
            }
            else{
                $('.addRow').show();
                }   

    })  

    $(document).on("click", '.delRow', function (event) {
        $(this).parent('tr').css('display','none'); 
        count--;

        if(count== 4)   
        {
            $('.addRow').hide();
            }
            else{
                $('.addRow').show();
                }       
    });
```

**HTML**

```
<table width="278" border="0" align="left" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="emailTable">
        <tr>
          <td width="207" align="left"><input name="" value="Enter Friend’s mobile no" type="text" onfocus="if(this.value == 'Enter Friend’s mobile no') {this.value=''}" onblur="if(this.value == ''){this.value ='Enter Friend’s mobile no'}" placeholder="Enter Friend’s mobile no" autocomplete="off"/></td>
          <td width="71" align="right" valign="top"><div class="addRow">Add</div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr  class="input1" style="display:none;">
          <td align="left"><input name="input" value="Enter Friend’s mobile no" type="text" onfocus="if(this.value == 'Enter Friend’s mobile no') {this.value=''}" onblur="if(this.value == ''){this.value ='Enter Friend’s mobile no'}" placeholder="Enter Friend’s mobile no" autocomplete="off"/></td>
          <td valign="middle" class="delRow">X</td>
        </tr>
        <tr  class="input2" style="display:none;">
          <td align="left"><input name="input2" value="Enter Friend’s mobile no" type="text" onfocus="if(this.value == 'Enter Friend’s mobile no') {this.value=''}" onblur="if(this.value == ''){this.value ='Enter Friend’s mobile no'}" placeholder="Enter Friend’s mobile no" autocomplete="off"/></td>
         <td valign="middle" class="delRow">X</td>
        </tr>
        <tr  class="input3" style="display:none;">
          <td align="left"><input name="input3" value="Enter Friend’s mobile no" type="text" onfocus="if(this.value == 'Enter Friend’s mobile no') {this.value=''}" onblur="if(this.value == ''){this.value ='Enter Friend’s mobile no'}" placeholder="Enter Friend’s mobile no" autocomplete="off"/></td>
          <td valign="middle" class="delRow">X</td>
        </tr>
        <tr  class="input4" style="display:none;">
          <td align="left"><input name="input4" value="Enter Friend’s mobile no" type="text" onfocus="if(this.value == 'Enter Friend’s mobile no') {this.value=''}" onblur="if(this.value == ''){this.value ='Enter Friend’s mobile no'}" placeholder="Enter Friend’s mobile no" autocomplete="off"/></td>
          <td valign="middle" class="delRow">X</td>
        </tr>
          </table>
```

Comment: You don't believe in punctuation?

Comment: sorry I m in hurry so .. :)

Comment: I understand. Might not be attractive to read, though. Just saying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add a row, you assume that `.inputX` (`X being count+1`) is currently not shown, which need not be the case.

The solution is to find the first hidden row and show that instead when adding a row.

i.e.

```
var count = 1;

$('.addRow').click(function () {
    count++;

    // show the first hidden row, instead of .inputX which may already be visible
    $('tr:hidden:first').show(); 

    // add will ONLY increase the value of count
    // so no need of else here
    if(count == 4) $('.addRow').hide();
});

$(document).on("click", '.delRow', function (event) {
    $(this).closest('tr').hide();
    count--;

    // no need of any condition here, as removing will take count below 4
    $('.addRow').show();
});
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/pnR8e/5/